# postgis/haversine accuracy: which one is best?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postgis

I'm having an issue with calculating distances.

I have installed postgis, and I'm saving Lng/Lat points in the database

```
CREATE TABLE geo (gid serial PRIMARY KEY, geo geography)
```

For inserting a record, this is what I do:

```
INSERT INTO geo (geo) VALUES (ST_MAKEPOINT(Lng,Lat)::geography))
```

When I do the following query with some Lng/Lat variables, I get the following output:

```
SELECT gid, ST_DISTANCE(geo, ST_MAKEPOINT(Lng2,Lat2)::geography) FROM geo;
----
OUTPUT: 1    424.02930940m
```

Secondly, when I do the exact same calculation with the following formula (haversine formula in javascript), I get a slightly different output.

```
/*
const coords1/2 = {
  lat: // latitude,
  lng: // longitude
};
*/

export const haversine = (coords1, coords2) => {
  var R = 6371000;
  var x1 = coords2.lat - coords1.lat;
  var dLat = x1.toRad();
  var x2 = coords2.lng - coords1.lng;
  var dLon = x2.toRad();
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(coords1.lat.toRad()) * Math.cos(coords2.lat.toRad()) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
};
----
OUTPUT: 422.20392010m
```

It's a difference of 2 meters, but I need the most accurate of the 2. It's for an app for geocaching.

I'm currently using the haversine formula in my app, but I'm thinking about switching to postgis because it would simplify my queries a lot.

**Which one can I rely on the most?**

Comment: I suspect st_distance will be better - the haversine formula measures great circle distances AFAIK, so over shorter distances the geodesic distance will be better. In your case - assuming you are in one region - using a projection appropriate for your area and doing st_distance on geometry type might be most accurate.

Comment: It's for small distances, max 10 000 meters. Should I convert all my geography objects to geometry or is 10 000 meters okay for accurancy to do with geography?

Comment: I have to correct myself: it's for all distances, but the shorter at the point, the more important that the distance is correct. If the point is in brussels and you're in new york, it doesn't matter if it's 9000 or 10000 km, because either way, you cant check in. But if the point is in brussels and your in brussels, it matters if its 100 or 150 m. because it has a check in range in meters.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know enough about the st_distance function to be able to answer that!